# Create and consume web service on local machine by using WAMP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, localhost

Is it possible to create an environment on local machine( i.e. **localhost**) where we can create and consume web service using PHP?

Is there any flow to create a web service like environment on localhost?

I would like to create an environment on localhost for web services where local machines, on intranet, get connected to main server (here again it's local machine) and can consume web services.

Like on `internet` we have Web Servers from where we can create and consume web services, Can we do the same on localhost?

Edit:

I am using `WAMP` with

> PHP 5.3 
> Apache 2.* 
>  MySQL 5
> Windows 8

Comment: Yes, you can use the web services using SOAP in PHP.

Comment: Try following for more free web services : http://www.webservicex.net/ws/default.aspx

Comment: @nullpointer, Please explain an bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to create a local web service. You will need a local web server (like IIS or [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)) to execute PHP locally.

Access you PHP application in your browser using `http://localhost/<yourApp>.php` and provide any webservice at a local URL as well, e.g. `http://localhost/<yourService>.php`. Your application can then access the webservice using the local URL.

This works both for REST or SOAP-style services.

EDIT: Your edit shows that you already set up a local environment to develop and test webservices. You should really be more specific in your question, maybe you are looking for a tutorial to create web services with PHP in genereal. If so, Google will be your best friend: https://www.google.de/#q=create+web+service+using+php+tutorial

Comment: Can I have a steps to setup the same? I also have edited my system configuration.

Comment: My aim was to ask is that, Does it requires to setup like `wsdl` in local machine too?

Comment: WSDL is not a software you could setup, it is the definition language usually used with SOAP web services. If this is what you are up to, mabye this tutorial will help: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/